# Difference between // and ''

Tags: ruby

1. What is the difference between `//` and `''` here?

   ```
   123.to_s.split(//)  #=> ["1", "2", "3"]
   123.to_s.split('')  #=> ["1", "2", "3"]
   ```

   Both give the same result.
2. What is `//` for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 `''` is a string, and `//` is a regular expression.

Any position in a string adjacent to a character can be assumed to implicitly include `''`. In other words, adding `''` to a position in a string does not change the content of the string:

```
'' + 'foo' # => 'foo'
'foo' + '' + 'bar' # => 'foobar'
'foo' + 'bar' # => 'foobar'
'foo' + '' # => 'foo'
```

Therefore, a string `'abc'` can be considered to be `'a'` + `''` + `'b'` + `''` + `'c'`, and hence, splitting `'abc'` by `''` results in `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Similarly, any position in a string adjacent to a character matches `//`. Therefore, splitting `'abc'` by `//` results in `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

2 The particular regex `//` may not be useful, but regexes in general are useful, and there is no reason to particularly prohibit `//`.

Comment: Ah - this makes more sense :)

Answer (score 4):

**Q1**: `''` is an empty String, whereas `//` is an empty `Regexp`:

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > ''.class
# => String 

2.0.0p247 :002 > //.class
# => Regexp
```

`String#split` happens to accept both Strings and Regexp objects when deciding what to split on. Because adding an empty String to a String doesn't change the string, the string can be thought of as `'1' + '' + '2' + '' + '3'`. Splitting against the empty string, therefore, will break the original string into individual characters.

Similarly, an empty Regexp matches any position next to a character, so `split` splits on every character in this case too. That's why they have the same result.

**Q2** I can't think of many (any?) uses for an empty Regexp :)

**EDIT**: @sawa is correct. Humbly updated.